# What is the word to use to describe the process of a person returning back to the original place after initially migrating to a different place?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person moves from their original place of residence to another place which we call as migration. What should we say if the person comes back to the same place after a while?

Comment: Just a comment: Strictly speaking 'migration' is just moving, changing places. Birds migrate (leave and return, etc.). Maybe with people we tend to think of 'one-direction migration'.

Comment: I was thinking you were looking for something like 'hearth-and-home' phrase. Seems you need a neutral/technical term. ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! That is a very good question. It is considered good practice to add a sentence with a gap to your single-word-request for others to more clearly understand you question, e.g. "When I poke a jelly and it moves in a wavy motion, it is _____" where the answer might be "wobbling". Your question is very clear and well-written, so I don't think it needs one, but I would advise doing it in future single-word-requests.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you are looking for is *Repatriate*

From Merriam-Webster:

> [Repatriate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repatriate) *verb*
>
> : to restore or return to the country of origin, allegiance, or
> citizenship

Sample:

> After living in Brazil for 14 years, John repatriated to the United
> States.

Comment: The process (as the OP wants) would be 'repatriation'. This however doesn't fit the case when a person migrates within their country of birth. E.g. a Montanan may migrate to New York, live their for many years, then come back to Montana. This won't be repatriation.

Answer (score 1):

According to English Language Learners Dictionary: returnee
: someone who returns to a place or activity; especially :
someone who returns to a country after being in another country in prison, in military service, etc.
The process of returning can be called:
return, coming back, comeback, homecoming.
For example:
HOMECOMING - 
Your homecoming is your return to your home or your country after being away for a long time 
(CollinsCobuild).
COMEBACK - 
a return to a former position or condition 
(Merriam-Webster's).

Comment: “Returnee” describes the person and does a good job of it. But the OP asked for a word to describe the *process* of returning. Consider [re-entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/re-entry).